# TFS Proxy alternatives

Tags: tfs, development-environment

[TFS Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252490%28VS.80%29.aspx) is designed to enable Team Foundation Server to mirror source control files to other Team Foundation Servers - very useful for geographically distributed teams.

We're investingating using this since we have distributed teams but would like to know: are there any alternatives to TFS Proxy before we fork out money for the licenses?

Comment: Do you already used TFS?

Comment: @rein: (somewhat off topic might might impact the best answer): why "unfortunately"?

Comment: @Richard: I'd have to guess it's because of the price. Microsoft don't make it cheap for non-partners.
@rein: I don't have a solution for you, as I'm not aware of a Proxy alternative to TFS Proxy that uses TFS still. SourceGear is one to look at (especially if you use the free 5-licence TFS Workgroup and are looking to upgrade). Perhaps you can use a VPN instead of TFS Proxy? (emphasis on "perhaps"!)

Comment: @Richard "unfortunately" because if we weren't using it we could look at integrating alternatives such as Git. Don't get me wrong, TFS is awesome - it's just a little costly at times - especially when we need TFS Proxy for a team of 3 people.

Comment: @Codesleuth Thanks - I'll look at SourceGear. The problem isn't having someone VPN, it's a question of having restricted bandwidth to pull down changes. Our WAN connection is rather slow and so we would like to have the local server be as close to the developers as possible.

Comment: @rein: Understood, at least that problem is being largely fixed in TFS2010.

Comment: What are you looking to do rein?  Maybe we can offer a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Ryan. Hi Ryan. We simply want to be able to have a remote office (with 3 people in it) check out/in source. Since the line between the central and remote locations is shocking (and we pay per MB) we want to minimise traffic between the central and remote locations. To accomplish this we want to setup a local repository at the remote site and sync the remote and the central sites.

Comment: Well then you are certainly heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Teamprise's Remote Accelerator: http://www.componentsource.com/products/teamprise-remote-accelerator/summary.html which is a TFS "proxy for a single user".